# Row name based on column ID in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a little problem. I'm very new to mysql and I'm creating some sort of basic database of cats. I'm adding 100 positions to database through that code:

```
 $result_set = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO koty2 (name, age, breed, author, tag, image) VALUES (:name, :age, :breed, :author, :tag, :image)");

 $result_set->execute(array(
':name' => $name,
':age' => $age,
':breed' => $breed,
':author' => $author,
':tag' => $tag,
':image' => $image

 ));

 for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {

 $result_set->execute(array(
':name' => $name,
':age' => $age,
':breed' => $breed,
':author' => $author,
':tag' => $tag,
':image' => $image
 ));
```

I tried multiple ways of adding the $name to the database with row's ID which is auto incremented - so it would be `"Name+ID"`. So far I failed. Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's just a part of practice. My friend is some sort of my mentor, I'm amateur atm, he gives me various tasks and exercises to do. That's one of them.

Comment: if all 101 records are the same, just `echo $name;` ought to do it

Comment: I think I worded that wrong. Damn. I mean, I want to add 100 cats to database with their names including ID's. Not just displaying it.

Comment: You want to include `ID` in name, or a separate column form `ID`?

Comment: In name. ATM $name = "name". I want it to be $name = "name+ID".

Comment: Assuming ID is a column does this work `INSERT INTO koty2 (name) VALUES (:name+ID)`?

Answer (score 1):

One work around is, you can first insert the data you want to insert, get the last inserted ID, then just update the name by concatenating the name and ID. See below code:

```
    // insert first
    $result_set = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO koty2 (name, age, breed, author, tag, image) VALUES (:name, :age, :breed, :author, :tag, :image)");
    $result_set->execute(array(
        ':name' => $name,
        ':age' => $age,
        ':breed' => $breed,
        ':author' => $author,
        ':tag' => $tag,
        ':image' => $image
    ));

    // get the inserted ID
    $last_ins_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // update the inserted name
    $update_row = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE koty2 SET name = :name WHERE ID = :id");
    $update_row->execute(array(
        ':name' => $name . $last_ins_id,
        ':id' => $last_ins_id
    ));
```

Im not sure if this is the best solution but this logic will still do the work

Comment: This is what I would do - if I were unable to choose my friends/mentors more carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I just added $i to the loop, so it's like $result_set->execute(array(
  ':name' => $name.$i, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the inserted auto-incremented ID everytime you insert a new Cat( xD ), you can use:

```
$pdo->lastInsertId();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

This will echo the whole column "$Name $CatID" do what you want:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT name, catID FROM koty2");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
  print "Name: <p>{$row[0] $row[1]}</p>";
}
```

For more, check:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: @abracadaver I disagree. The OP wants a particular outcome, but they haven't stated the mechanism by which it must be achieved.